# Visual studio code review

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2012 that my reviewer can review the changes that were made only since the last review?
Right now when I submit my code for review, the reviewer sends his comments. But when I make the changes mentioned in those comments, I have to submit the code again and my reviewer doesn't find a way to compare it against the previous review.

Comment: Have you tried using shelvesets to review the code rather than changesets?

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know that is possible. Will give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

As @JamesTupper said you have 2 choices for Code Reviews in VS/TFS: Review a Shelveset (pre-checkin), review a changeset (post-checkin).

For your desired workflow, you can submit a code review before you check-in your changes.  This will automatically create a shelveset that the reviewer will use.  If they come back with comments/changes, you can make the changes in your local workspace, then submit a new Code Review which will create a new shelveset with all the original changes + the new changes.

Comment: Oh yes.. That happens. But is there a way in which reviewer can check only the new changes? So that he does not have to go through the old changes again?

Comment: In that case I would suggest using the post-checkin workflow and submit changesets to the reviewer.  Make changes, check-in, submit for review, make more changes based on comments, check-in again, submit new review.